# Is there a way to update multiple documents with different values in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm feeling like there probably isn't a way to do this, but here's what I want to accomplish, I have an array of products to update like so:

```
const productsToUpdate = [
    {
        "imgUrls": {
            "base": [
                "https://files.cdn.printful.com/files/ba1/ba13faa1332b7f18ec847cb9f4d79868_preview.png"
            ],
            "side": [
                "https://files.cdn.printful.com/files/ba1/ba13faa1332b7f18ec847cb9f4d79868_preview.png"
            ]
        },
        "_id": "5dd6173cf50c1d1a40fe7c2c",
        "category": "MENS",
        "name": "JavaScript is Cool",
        "price": "27.50" 
    },
        {
        "imgUrls": {
            "base": [
                "https://files.cdn.printful.com/files/ba1/ba13faa1332b7f18ec847cb9f4d79868_preview.png"
            ],
            "side": [
                "https://files.cdn.printful.com/files/ba1/ba13faa1332b7f18ec847cb9f4d79868_preview.png"
            ]
        },
        "_id": "5dd6173cf50c1d1a40fe7c2c",
        "category": "MENS",
        "name": "Testing",
        "price": "25.50" 


    }
]
```

This data structure matches the data of products currently stored in my database. Basically, I need to find a current product by _id and be able to update either the category, price, imgUrls, or name or all of the above.

I've done some research and know I can grab all the ids from the toUpdate arr and then do something like

```
Collection.update({ _id: { $in: arrOfIds }, {}, {multi: true}))
```

But I'm not sure how to fill in the query to have the correct category/price/name etc.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or if you need more information please let me know!

Comment: "be able to update either the category, price, imgUrls, or name or all of the above." - could you provide more details on the way you need to update them ?

Comment: Sure! Basically, I need to take the products in the products to update array, and if the value of imgUrls, price, category, or name has changed, update that same value in the database.

Comment: Do you want to focus on those specific fields or just update entire document ? I',m asking because the fields you mentioned are the only ones you provided so wouldn't it be easier to replace whole documents ? Or are there any other fields that you don't want to get removed ?

Comment: Ahh. Sorry. There are other fields, but they’ll remain constant so I removed them from the initial question to save space. Additionally, it’s possible that only one of those fields will change in a request as opposed to all of them. I could do it as a series of single requests, but I was hoping to have a mass update option.

Answer (score 1):

The "mass-update" or rather the most efficient way of that kind of updates is called [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/). Since there are is more fields in your database and you don't want to lose them you need to use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) operator.

```
const productsToUpdate = [
    {
        "imgUrls": {
            "base": [
                "https://files.cdn.printful.com/files/ba1/ba13faa1332b7f18ec847cb9f4d79868_preview.png"
            ],
            "side": [
                "https://files.cdn.printful.com/files/ba1/ba13faa1332b7f18ec847cb9f4d79868_preview.png"
            ]
        },
        "_id": "5dd6173cf50c1d1a40fe7c2c",
        "category": "MENS",
        "name": "JavaScript is Cool",
        "price": "27.50" 
    },
        {
        "imgUrls": {
            "base": [
                "https://files.cdn.printful.com/files/ba1/ba13faa1332b7f18ec847cb9f4d79868_preview.png"
            ],
            "side": [
                "https://files.cdn.printful.com/files/ba1/ba13faa1332b7f18ec847cb9f4d79868_preview.png"
            ]
        },
        "_id": "5dd6173cf50c1d1a40fe7c2c",
        "category": "MENS",
        "name": "Testing",
        "price": "25.50" 


    }
];

let toUupdate = product => ({
    updateOne: { 
        "filter": { "_id": product._id }, 
        "update": { "$set": { category: product.category, name: product.name, price: product.price }  }   
    }
})

db.collection.bulkWrite(productsToUpdate.map(toUupdate);

console.log(updates);
```